# Copernicus C3S Dataset: details on CRS and Projection

Tags: coordinate-system, copernicus

I am working with Copernicus C3S data and I am having difficulty interpreting the descriptions relating to the Projection entry on the portal. I understand that Regular lat/lon means WGS84, my problem is when the projections are described, as in the case of the data in the link below, an identification code is not indicated (such as EPSG or Authority id) and the description Lambert azimuthal equal area Is not enough. Within the metadata there is no none of this is specified and by contacting the Copernicus support service they cannot help me because they say that this data is provided by external data providers who no longer manage the support.

How can I get this information?

Copernicus data: https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/sis-hydrology-meteorology-derived-projections?tab=overview